# NuGet package manager console does not work

Tags: visual-studio-2017, nuget

- Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 Version 15.9.7
- Windows 7 Professional SP1

I'm using NuGet Package Manager Console for the first time. I've used NuGet Solution GUI console before.

However I'm getting this error.

```
Each package is licensed to you by its owner. NuGet is not responsible for, nor does it grant any licenses to, third-party packages. Some packages may include dependencies which are governed by additional licenses. Follow the package source (feed) URL to determine any dependencies.

Package Manager Console Host Version 4.9.3.5777

Type 'get-help NuGet' to see all available NuGet commands.

PM> npm init -v
npm : openssl config failed: error:02001003:system library:fopen:No such process
At line:1 char:1
+ npm init -v
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (openssl config ...No such process:String) [], RemoteException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

5.6.0
openssl config failed: error:02001003:system library:fopen:No such process
PM>
```

I have no clue what is going on. Any ideas?

The ultimate purpose for me is following this tutorial.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/javascript-client?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. OPENSSL_CONF environment variable prevented running npm. It now works after deleting the variable.

Comment: Hi Katsutoshi, so glad to hear that your issue is solved and thank you for sharing the solution. Please mark it as answer when you have free time, that will also help other community members to easier search this useful information, thanks.